# Div refresh does not work - jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem and make some research but did not reach anything.

I insert db with jquery. However, after inserting , what i want is that making refresh the div

```
  if(response =='ok'){
             alert("Başarıyla eklendi");
             $('#loaddiv').fadeOut('tabberlive').load('urlofmypage').fadeIn("slow");
        }
```

What's wrong with that ?

Comment: Is the db query inserting the data ok? What is the problem you're having? I can't tell from your question.

Comment: yes i look at console ok is comes

Comment: I would go with what userD suggests and see if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What does it do and what you want it to do. You did not provide any relevant information that lets us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you could do something like this

```
$('#loaddiv').fadeOut('tabberlive', function() {
    $(this).load('urlofmypage', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});​
```

**DEMO:** Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/63VNe/) works ? Is this want you want ?